# Saving video to SD card while live streaming to YouTube using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi so that it live streams video to YouTube using the Raspberry Pi camera and also saves the video to the SD Card for backup, in case the internet gets disconnected. I used Alex Ellis's [guide](https://blog.alexellis.io/live-stream-with-docker/) to set it up, which is basically a docker image that anyone can download and set it up. He sets up the live stream to YouTube but doesn't save the video offline.

So, I tinkered with his code and found that he used FFmpeg to stream to YouTube. The following line is basically the heart of his method to stream:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 40 -b 8000000 -g 40 | ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ab 128k -g 40 -strict experimental -f flv -r 30 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$1
```

I read up about FFmpeg and apparently, to save this stream to my SD card all I need to do is add the directory where I want to save my video to the end of this code. I modified it like so at the end of the line:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 40 -b 8000000 -g 40 | ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ab 128k -g 40 -strict experimental -f flv -r 30 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$1 /home/pi/Desktop/my_video.mp4
```

However, when I ran this, the terminal threw this error:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/my_video.mp4: No such file or directory
```

This path, however, definitely exists by default in all Raspberry Pi's. I'm not sure what's wrong here, can someone please help me out?

P.S: as an additional side question, I read up the documentation on FFmpeg and it specifically says not to use the -re argument when using a live input source, but Alex uses it anyways. Should I substitute it with something different? It works fine right now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tee muxer:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 40 -b 8000000 -g 40 | ffmpeg -i - -re -f lavfi -i anullsrc -map 0 -map 1 -c:v copy -c:a aac -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<stream key>|/home/pi/Desktop/my_video.mp4"
```

> P.S: as an additional side question, I read up the documentation on FFmpeg and it specifically says not to use the -re argument when using a live input source, but Alex uses it anyways. Should I substitute it with something different? It works fine right now though.

- Do not use `-re` for live inputs.
- `-strict experimental` isn't needed unless your `ffmpeg` is super old.
- Use the simpler [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter to generate silent audio instead of `/dev/zero`.
- Your command is mixing `-c:v copy` ([stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy)) with video encoding options. These are mutually exclusive so the video encoding options are being ignored.

  - If you want to re-encode instead of stream copy then remove `-c:v copy` and consider using `-c:v h264_omx` instead if your `ffmpeg` was configured with `--enable-omx-rpi`.
  - If you want to re-encode set your desired `fps` in `raspivid` instead of changing it in `ffmpeg`.

See:

- [tee muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Tee Muxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepseudo-muxer)

Comment: Can you please have a look at a question I've posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61970598/unplayable-video-after-running-ffmpeg-command